# PowerShell refactoring functions to one main function

Tags: powershell

I have several functions using the same method to call another function or do certain things:

```
function doMyFn
{
    if ($getProject -match 'all')
    {
        foreach ($project in $projectAllowedLst)
        {
             # Section a
             # Parameters to be passed to the script block below. In this
             # case it is $project.
             # The command or function that are being called are to be set
             # here (based on the $project).
        }
    }
    elseif ($getProject -match ',')
    {
        $projects = $getProject -split (',')

        foreach ($project in $projects)
        {
             # Section b
             # Parameters to be passed to the script block below. In this
             # case it is $project.
             # The command or function that are being called are to be set
             # here (based on the $project).
        }
    }
    elseif ($getProject -notmatch ',')
    {
          # Section c
          # Parameters to be passed to the script block below. In this
          # case it is $getProject.
          # The command or function that are being called are to be set
          # here (based on the $getProject).
    }
}
```

Another function that looks like this:

```
if (testBeforeBackup $project){doProjectBackup $project} else {updateXML $project}
```

And a block with `switch` and `function` like below. All these are being used in the main function above in all the sections named section a, b, and c.

```
# Function  1
function one {
    if ($getProject -match 'all')
    {
        foreach ($project in @('de', 'idm'))
        {
            copyXML $project
        }
    }
    elseif ($getProject -match ',')
    {
        $projects = $getProject -split (',')

        foreach ($project in $projects)
        {
            copyXML $project
        }
    }
    elseif ($getProject -notmatch ',')
    {
        copyXML $getProject
    }
}

# Function 2
function two {
    if ($getProject -match 'all')
    {
        foreach ($project in $projectAllowedLst)
        {
            $dstAppList[$project] = readNewAppName $project
        }
    }
    elseif ($getProject -match ',')
    {
        $projects = $getProject -split (',')

        foreach ($project in $projects)
        {
            $dstAppList[$project] = readNewAppName $project
        }
    }
    elseif ($getProject -notmatch ',')
    {
            $dstAppList[$getProject] = readNewAppName $getProject
    }
}

# Function 4
function four {

    if ($getProject -match 'all')
    {
        foreach ($project in $projectAllowedLst)
        {
            switch($project)
            {
                'de'{
                        if (testBeforeBackup $project)
                        {
                            deleteFiles $e_dst_folder $noDeleteEfolders
                        }
                    }
                'home'{
                        if (testBeforeBackup $project)
                        {
                            deleteFiles $home_dst_folder $noDeleteHomefolders
                        }
                    }
                'idm'{
                        if (testBeforeBackup $project)
                        {
                            deleteFiles $i_dst_folder $noDeleteifolders
                        }
                    }
            }
            copyProject $project
        }
    }
    elseif ($getProject -match ',')
    {
        $projects = $getProject -split (',')

        foreach ($project in $projects)
        {
            switch($project)
            {
                'de'{
                        if (testBeforeBackup $project)
                        {
                            deleteFiles $e_dst_folder $noDeleteEfolders
                        }
                    }
                'home'{
                        if (testBeforeBackup $project)
                        {
                            deleteFiles $home_dst_folder $noDeleteHomefolders
                        }
                    }
                'idm'{
                        if (testBeforeBackup $project)
                        {
                            deleteFiles $i_dst_folder $noDeleteifolders
                        }
                    }
            }

            copyProject $project
        }
    }
    elseif ($getProject -notmatch ',')
    {
        switch($getProject)
        {
            'de'{
                    if (testBeforeBackup $getProject)
                    {
                        deleteFiles $e_dst_folder $noDeleteEfolders
                    }
                }
            'home'{
                    if (testBeforeBackup $getProject)
                    {
                        deleteFiles $home_dst_folder $noDeleteHomefolders
                    }
                }
            'idm'{
                    if (testBeforeBackup $getProject)
                    {
                        deleteFiles $i_dst_folder $noDeleteifolders
                    }
                }
        }
        copyProject $getProject
    }
}
```

There are some variables that will be accessed from the script scope so no worries about the other variables.

How can I refactor it in a better way?

Comment: I don't think it is clear what you are trying to accomplish here. Do you think your function calls involve too much code as there is a lot of repetition? Are you trying to combine your functions.... Also I only see one function here and 3 sets of code. I could see you having scope confusion issues but I'm a little lost with this one.

Comment: If you just add a block `Param([Switch]$A;[Switch]$B;[Switch]$C)` to your function with switches you can call your function the way you like it.

Comment: i have added my 3 functions that they are using the same template but to do different things within, i want to combine them all into 1 function and call all other functions as parameters to be used in that main function or if any other suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want your function to react to `all` as a single parameter, not as say "wall,bash" - this thing *matches* `all` too. What you ask is known as "properly parsing parameters", and in fact, you only should treat the "all" case, everything else can be madde into an array and then treated as an array in subsequent code.

Assuming `$projectAllowedLst` is what you should parse if received "all" in the parameter, this should make the trick:

```
if ($getProject -ieq "all") {$getProject=$projectAllowedLst}
foreach ($project in $getProject) {
    # main body, only dependent on $project
}
```

UPDATE: You should do more with your projects, I see that there are logically linked variables in your code, that seem to hold various data about one project. So, you make your project into a hash table, with each project description containing fields for destination folder, protected folders (?) and name. An example:

```
$projectAllowedLst = @() # an array of projects
$projectAllowedLst += @{ 
    "Name" = "de";
    "DestinationFolder" = $e_dst_folder;
    "ProtectedFolders" = $noDeleteEfolders
} # "de" project
# same for other projects.
```

Then, for example, your "function four" would be rewritten as such:

```
function four (param $getProject) {
    if ($getProject -ieq "all") {$getProject=$projectAllowedLst}
    foreach ($project in $getProject) {
       deleteFiles $project.DestinationFolder $project.ProtectedFolders
       copyProject $project # better rewrite this one to use full project data
    }
}
```

This will, though, disable you from hardcoding `"de","idm"` in your functions, because you will have to stuff full project data into `copyXML` for it to work, but will generally make your code cleaner and data more structured, and can potentially allow you to expand to supporting more projects without rewriting every single function.

UPDATE 2: If you, by some reason, decide to allow the user (or yourself) to pass a list of project names, you can still do that but you'll have to control the object type yourself. An example:

```
function copyXML (param $projects) {
    foreach ($project in $projects) {
        if ($project.getType().fullname -eq "System.String") {
            # we've been given a string - search for name
            $detailedProject = $projectAllowedLst | where {$_.name -eq $project}
            if ($detailedProject.getType().fullName -ne "System.Collections.Hashtable") 
                { $detailedProject=$detailedProject[0]}
            # TWO OR MORE projects? Take first one
            $project=$detailedProject
        } 
        # do your stuff with complete project data
    }
}
```

Comment: my $projectAllowedLst = @('a', 'b', 'c'), so there is a difference in the user input , the cases are 
1 - inputs : all
2 - inputs : a,c
3 - inputs : b

so there is difference in all 3 cases

Comment: @Vagho See updated post, there's a solution to implement if you've been provided a project (a hashtable) or a string (its name).